# Is Smetanich's logic the second from the top in the lattice of intermediate logics?

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

Consider the lattice of consistent superintuitionistic logics, also known as intermediate logics. Smetanich's logic is the logic obtained from intuitionistic logic by adding the axiom $((\neg q \rightarrow p) \rightarrow (((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p))$. I have read it is the unique coatom in the lattice of intermediate logics. But that is a weaker condition than being second from the top. More precisely, if you remove classical logic from the lattice of intermediate logics, would Smetanich's logic be the new top element?